# How to put a string into a list

Tags: clojure, lisp

I want to put the value of an empty string `""` into an empty list.

I currently have the idea of `(cons "" '())`. Is there any other (or better) way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or indeed just `'("")`. `list` is the more general list constructor, since it will evaluate its arguments, but for creating a list of constants, you can use `quote` (recall that `'x` is shorthand for `(quote x)`).

You should also consider creating a vector instead, with `[""]`. Vectors are often a better place to store data than lists, in Clojure.

Comment: Except for one thing regarding `'("")`.  If your code or other code expects to use destructive operations on a list structure such as that, or that contains that, be aware that unlike `(cons "" ())` and `(list "")`, `'("")` might not return a new list each time (depends on the Lisp you use, and sometimes even the implementation of the Lisp you use).  In general, it's a good idea to avoid things like `'("")`.

Comment: I guess since this was posted under the `lisp` tag, that advice may be relevant, but since he also posted under `clojure`, I imagine that's the language OP is actually using. There is no such behavior to be concerned about in Clojure. For one thing, there is no destructive operation that works on lists! Writing `(cons "" ())` would be horrible Clojure style; `(list "")` is fine, and arguably more readable, but behaves the same.

Answer (score 4):

Use `list`:

```
> (list "")
("")
```